# Changing of account type on google cloud from business to individual

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I created a new google cloud account, using net banking option, which required a prepayment. I received my $300 free credits. But later, when it asked me to verify my business, I found that I registered my billing account type as business.

I asked duet AI about changing my account type from business to individual, it said me to create a new billing account as individual. So I created a new billing account as individual, again with netbanking and prepayment. However I don't have my free credits in my new billing account.

I want to know two things

1. How can i transfer my free credits to my new billing account?
2. How can i get refund of prepayment for my first billing account?

Comment: Add that comment(about refund) content in the answer also. I will mark it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you create a Cloud Billing account and its associated Google payments profile, **you cannot modify the account type of the Google payments profile after signing up**.When you create a Google payments profile, you are prompted to select the account type, to create either an **"individual"** or **"business"** profile. In some countries, this selection affects your tax options. Also, only "Business" types can have multiple payments profile users. So, you cannot change the account type manually.

To use a Google payments profile with a different account type, [create a new Cloud Billing account.](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/create-billing-account) If you have a Cloud Billing account that is billed by invoice, then creating a new, self-serve billing account might not be the best option for you. To modify the settings on your invoiced account, contact your [Account Representative](https://support.google.com/paymentscenter/answer/11543916?hl=en-IN) or [Cloud Billing Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing) for assistance.Also, you **cannot transfer the free-trial** $300 credits to other accounts and wouldn’t get any refund for the free-trial account.

**You can upgrade your Cloud Billing account at any time after starting the Free Trial**, to ensure that your resources keep running uninterrupted after the trial ends.When you upgrade, the following conditions apply:

**1. If you upgrade before the trial is over:** Any remaining, unexpired Free Trial credits remain in your Cloud Billing account. You can continue to use the resources you created during the Free Trial without interruption.
For resources you use in excess of what's covered by any remaining credit, your form of payment on file is charged (credit card or bank account).

**2. If you upgrade within 30 days of the end of the trial:** Your resources are marked for deletion, but you might be able to recover them.

**3. If you upgrade more than 30 days after the end of the trial**, your Free Trial resources are lost.

Refer to the [document](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/free-cloud-features?sjid=12100389203262520966-AP#steps-to-upgrade-your-account) to upgrade your cloud billing account

**EDIT:**

You can request a refund in GCP console and sign in to the Payment overview page and follow the steps provided in the [document](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/resolve-issues#request_a_refund).

Comment: Okay, so if i close one of my account, how will i get refund of INR 1000 prepayment that i paid

Comment: You can request a refund in GCP console and sign in to the Payment overview page and follow the steps provided in the [document](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/resolve-issues#request_a_refund)